# working with git in windows commiting in os x

Tags: windows, macos, git, bash, visual-studio

I just bought a macbook pro to see how it is as a windows developer machine. I am using parallels desktop 9 for mac and it's really rocks. I want to use os x as much as poisable and only use windows for Visual Studio and windows only program, everything else I want to do in os x.

My main concern is git. I am sharing my projects folder with windows and my goal is to do all git related work from the mac bash terminal.

I am worried about line endings and special danish letters like ÅØÆ. Is it a bad idea to work in windows and commit in os x?

This is what I have found out so far:
- git config --global core.precomposeunicode true // so git can reconize øæå in filenames
- if it's a windows repository use core.autocrlf = true
- if it's on mac use core.autocrlf = input

So if I worked on a shared repository and everyone else is using windows with core.autocrlf = true what should I use when I commit from my mac, but do the coding in VS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Danish characters, but I work off windows through VMWare and I set the core.autocrif = true, since it will mess up my clickonce deployments otherwise.

That being said but I would match everyone else with core.autocrif = true, I have noticed things with line endings on the mac side if I'm editing db scripts but haven't ran into any issues with having this setting(mainly a web dev shop)

Comment: Thanks just tested autocrlf = true and it works. To remember this I wrote my first blog post http://martin-andersen.azurewebsites.net/setting-up-git-on-os-x/